# Node.js static folder reference not loading CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am currently developing a website using Node.js.
I just set up my 404 page, and it works fine when I go to something like `mywebsite.com/404` or another page that doesn't exist, but if I try access to something like `mywebsite.com/foo/bar`, which also doesn't exist, the assets like `CSS` and `JS` don't load. On the server, I am using:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And, on the page itself:

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I know that adding a `../` in front of the assets on the HTML will work, but that is not ideal. Any help?

My Folder Structure is something as follows:

```
Project Folder
|-App.js
|-views
  |-404.ejs
  |-home.ejs
|-public
  |-CSS
    |-Bootstrap.min.css
  |-js
  |-img
  |-font
```

Comment: could you please show us the structure of your folders? there is located the page that are you trying to show?

Comment: Since the URL starts with a `/`, you should not get the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Updated the post to include the file structure. As a note, I looked at the CSS in the 404 page, and it is requesting `/whatever/the/link/is/assets/css/boostrap.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

Use [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element on your 404 page (or every page!) and it will always request your assets using the base path you have specified.

For example, adding `<base href="http://example.com" /`> before your `</head>` tag will request every assets with `http://example.com` as the path so in your case, instead of `/foo/bar/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`, it will request `/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: The base element is for resolving relative URLs, but a URL starting with a slash is not relative, it's absolute. The OPs problem must be something else. Also, the base element should be added _inside_ the head element, not _before_.

Comment: @PatrickHund I would give it a try and yes, It's supposed to be inside the head (it was a typo).

Comment: @zGeek While this has fixed the problem, I would like to diagnose the underlying issue here, because I believe there is something else going on here

Comment: Is it possible if you can provide a live preview of this page?

Comment: As of right now this is only running in my test environment. I can provide the source code though